# Daily Temperatures

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**

is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/)

> Given a list of daily temperatures T, return a list such that, for
>   each day in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait
>   until a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this
>   is possible, put 0 instead.
>
> For example, given the list of temperatures T = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69,
>   72, 76, 73], your output should be [1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0].
>
> Note: The length of temperatures will be in the range [1, 30000]. Each
>   temperature will be an integer in the range [30, 100].

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} T
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var dailyTemperatures = function(T) {
  const findNextMaxTemp = (t, i) => {
    const myArr = T.slice(i + 1);
    if (!myArr.length) { return 0; }
    let k;
    return myArr.some((x, j) => (k = j, x > t))
      ? k + 1
      : 0;
  }
  return T.map(findNextMaxTemp);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised this solution passes a medium level question,
given that it's a brute-force implementation with quadratic time complexity (consider for example a long decreasing sequence as input).

That said, a couple of simple improvements are possible:

- The condition `if (!myArr.length) { return 0; }` is unnecessary.
- Instead of the `.some(...)` call with its side effect, it would be cleaner to use `findIndex`: `return myArr.findIndex(x => x > t) + 1`

And, as an exercise, I recommend to find an alternative algorithm that has linear time.

> Go from the end and use a stack to track potential higher temperature candidates.